# Rails "Getting Started" routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following the getting started tutorial here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I am finding routes quite confusing:

> We still need a way to list all our posts, so let's do that. We'll use a specific route from config/routes.rb:
>
> `posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index`

When adding this to my routes.rb file, I encounter an error

> SyntaxError
> /Users/example/blog/config/routes.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end #get 'posts/:format' => 'posts#index' ^ /Users/thoad/blog/config/routes.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end #get 'posts/:format' => 'posts#index' ^

When I just omit the line altogether, everything works fine...

So... why do I need that line, and could someone explain the structure of it to me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must say that bit of the documentation is a little misleading, but jump back a few steps in the documentation to [5 Getting up and running](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running) and you'll find the code

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :posts

  root to: "welcome#index"
end
```

This is what you should have in your `routes.rb` file, and it's what is responsible for producing the output that you have in your question.

If you put that into your `routes.rb` file, and then in a console, run `rake routes` you'll get the output

```
    posts GET    /posts(.:format)          posts#index
          POST   /posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
          PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
          DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
     root        /                         welcome#index
```

Notice that in that output, the first line is what is in your question. The routing system is pretty complex in Rails, so don't get too overwhelmed now. For now, stick with the very basics.

If you want to add routes to `Create`, `Read`, `Update, and`Delete`a record, then you want to use the`resources` method in your routes file, as shown above. This will automatically create 8 routes for you. Rails will automatically associate it with the appropriate controller as well so you must make sure you name things correctly.

Comment: great explanation, many thanks for taking the time to write it!

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

This is not a line you have to add to config/routes.rb. This line comes from running the following command: `rake routes`. The line means that action `index` in controller `posts` is responsible for handling the path `/posts`. The next step of the guide is creating said action. In your controllers and views, you can use `posts_path` in order to redirect to this specific path or link to it. Hope this helps.